# unable find Cellid,MCC,MNC,LAC value in nokia e71 through J2ME code

Tags: java-me, netbeans-7

How can I get cell id, MCC, LAC for Nokia E71?

I am using below code but unable find the cellid, MCC ,LAC value.

I try to find this value through j2me code.

Please help me to find this value

Code to get cell id:

> public static String getCellId() {
>           String out = "";
>           try {
>
> ```
>         out = System.getProperty("Cell-ID"); //            if (out == null || out.equals("null") || out.equals("")) { //                out = System.getProperty("CellID"); //            } //            if
> ```
>
> (out == null || out.equals("null") || out.equals("")) { //
>   System.getProperty("phone.cid"); //            }
>
> ```
>         if (out == null || out.equals("null") || out.equals("")) {
>             out = System.getProperty("com.nokia.mid.cellid");
>         }
>
>
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         return out == null ? "" : out;
>     }
>
>     return out == null ? "" : out;
> }
> ```

Code to get LAC:

> ```
> public static String getLAC() {
>         String out = "";
>         try {
>
>             if (out == null || out.equals("null") || out.equals("")) {
>                 out = System.getProperty("com.nokia.mid.lac");
>             }
>
>
>         } catch (Exception e) {
>             return out == null ? "" : out;
>         }
>
>         return out == null ? "" : out;
>     }
> ```

Code to get IMSI:

> ```
>  public static String getIMSI() {
>         String out = "";
>         try {
>
>             out = System.getProperty("IMSI");
>
>             if (out == null || out.equals("null") || out.equals("")) {
>                 System.getProperty("phone.cid");
>             }
>             if (out == null || out.equals("null") || out.equals("")) {
>                 out = System.getProperty("com.nokia.mid.mobinfo.IMSI");
>             }
>
>             if (out == null || out.equals("null") || out.equals("")) {
>                 out = System.getProperty("com.nokia.mid.imsi");
>             }
>
>
>         } catch (Exception e) {
>             return out == null ? "" : out;
>         }
>
>         return out == null ? "" : out;
>     }
> ```

Code to get MCC:

> ```
> public static String getMCC() {
>         String out = "";
>         try {
>
>             if (out == null || out.equals("null") || out.equals("")) {
>                 out = System.getProperty("phone.mcc");
>             }
>
>             if (out == null || out.equals("null") || out.equals("")) {
>                 out = System.getProperty("com.nokia.mid.mobinfo.IMSI");
>             }
>
>
>             if (out == null || out.equals("null") || out.equals("")) {
>                 out = getIMSI().equals("") ? "" : getIMSI().substring(0, 3);
>             }
>
>             if (out == null || out.equals("null") || out.equals("")) {
>                 out = System.getProperty("com.siemens.imei");
>             }
>
>             if (out == null || out.equals("null") || out.equals(""))//getMNC()
>
>             {
>                 if (out == null || out.equals("null") || out.equals("")) {
>                     out = System.getProperty("mcc");
>                 }
>             }
>
>
>         } catch (Exception e) {
>             return out == null ? "" : out;
>         }
>
>         return out == null ? "" : out;
>     }
> ```

Code to get MNC:

> ```
> public static String getMNC() {
>         String out = "";
>         try {
>
>             if (out == null || out.equals("null") || out.equals("")) {
>                 out = System.getProperty("phone.mnc");
>             }
>
>             if (out == null || out.equals("null") || out.equals("")) {
>                 out = getIMSI().equals("") ? "" : getIMSI().substring(3, 5);
>             }
>
>
>            if (out == null || out.equals("null") || out.equals("")) {
>                 out = getIMSI().equals("") ? "" : getIMSI().substring(3, 5);
>             }
>
>
>            if (out == null || out.equals("null") || out.equals(""))//getMNC()
>
>             {
>                 if (out == null || out.equals("null") || out.equals("")) {
>                     out = System.getProperty("mnc");
>                 }
>             }
>
>
>         } catch (Exception e) {
>             return out == null ? "" : out;
>         }
>
>         return out == null ? "" : out;
>     }
> ```

u use my code or not

Comment: public static String getMCC() {
        String out = "";
        try {

            if (out == null || out.equals("null") || out.equals("")) {
                out = System.getProperty("com.nokia.mid.countrycode");

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return out == null ? "" : out;
        }

        return out == null ? "" : out;
    }

Comment: through this code i got MCC. i resolve my problem my self

Comment: i am having the same problem i am using nokia c1 phone and cellid appears null can you say how can i resolve it ?

Comment: i up date my code please check  it.

Comment: have you signed the app in nokia for that ?

Comment: i have tried cellid = System.getProperty("com.nokia.mid.cellid"); but it returns null for my nokia c1 mobile.

Comment: ya i had used your code where System.getProperty("com.nokia.mid.cellid");  gives null

Comment: don't worry i  send u the another code wait

Comment: can you please send the code to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412139/find-location-on-non-gps-nokia-c1-phone-using-cellid-javame so that i can accept it if it works.

Comment: http://codepaste.net/kwax17 i send u the code use it.

Comment: if it is ok then accept my code.

Comment: if it's not working then u can't fetch these values

Comment: no still the cellid returns null

Comment: then it's only work on s60 series mobile change your handset.

Answer (score 0):

As far as Nokia is concerned, you need to get your app signed by the operator so that you are able to access those details.